# Careers: include country when filing CV

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

On the filing screen at careers.stackoverflow.com, there are fields for city, state or region, and postal code. But country is missing, so (for instance) you can't distinguish between Perth, UK and Perth, Australia. Please add a country field.

Comment: Never seen the field for a postcode.

Comment: And the postal code field will have to be extremely flexible to accomodate UK postcodes (W1A 1HQ), Australian (4321), and what do the Americans call 'em, oh yes **zipcodes**

Comment: we have found that country is not required to get credit cards to work internationally -- are you not able to file?

Comment: The confirmation e-mail I receive _does_ include the country field (which is empty obviously) which makes it look weird. Also, why include the state/region field?

Answer (score 1):

We don't require a country for the purposes of billing - it's more important to get your location correct on the location field in Personal Info and "Where do you want to work?" located on your CV.